# Did Jesus act out His parables?

Tags: catholicism, gospels, parables

We see in the parables of Jesus, many moments which  provide   for dramatic presentation, like the scene of the prodigal son envying the well-fed swines, or the father running to the gate to receive his son. It is hard to believe that Jesus said all those things without emotional attachment. He would have taken the assistance of the disciples and presented the parables in such a way that they stayed put in the hearts of those who listened. My question therefore, is: what does the Catholic Church say about the manner in which Jesus presented His parables ?

Comment: Interesting question, but I doubt Our Lord did so. Have a +1 for such a novelty question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indication in Catholic teaching that Our Lord "acted out" any of his parables. The [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11460a.htm) is completely mute on this subject.

The closest one can find is the Gospels that is even remotely connected  and it would be extremely stretching the limit of acting to say the least because it was not even a parable. Our Lord once wrote in the sand when the woman was caught in adultery.

> They were using this question as a trap, in order to have a basis for accusing him.
>
> But Jesus bent down and started to write on the ground with his finger.  When they kept on questioning him, he straightened up and said to them, “Let any one of you who is without sin be the first to throw a stone at her.” [(John 8: 6-8)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%208%3A6-7&version=NIV)

Comment: ... and what did He write ?

Comment: See Mark 7:31-37: "After he took him aside, away from the crowd, Jesus put his fingers into the man’s ears. Then he spit and touched the man’s tongue.  He looked up to heaven and with a deep sigh said to him, “Ephphatha!” (which means “Be opened!”).  At this, the man’s ears were opened, his tongue was loosened and he began to speak plainly." . Clearly, Jesus was expressive ---both in  words and deeds. In those days of no microphones and amplifiers, speaking aloud and using gestures to communicate , was only a natural means of expression.    T

Answer (score 1):

We don't see Jesus "acting" (physically moving to) his parables. Instead what is shown in scriptures is the vast relationship between every-day life and the parables. They depicted the message to be practiced "every-day". There are many categories for parables, specially the agricultural ones. Many people rejected his messages so he explained his messages through parables like Isaiah prophesied (John 12:38)